# How to convert MoneyField currency?

Tags: python, django

I created a management system for my Django app. In this app, the user has several customers and every customer has a `credit_limit` field. I am using `MoneyField` from `django-money` for this field so, users can select any currency. But I want to make some operations in this field like addition. For this I need each customer's `credit_limit` field to be converted to the same currency (dollar). But I couldn't find how to do this. I need help.

Here are my codes.

**models.py**

```
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
...
class Customer(models.Model):
   ...
    credit_limit = MoneyField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD', default=0)
...
```

**forms.py**

```
class NewCustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('customer_name', 'country', 'address', 'VATnumber', 'telephone', 'email', 'contact_person',
                  'credit_limit', 'risk_rating')
```

**views.py**

```
def customer(request):
    form_class = NewCustomerForm
    current_user = request.user
    userP = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=current_user)
    company = userP[0].company
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewCustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            newCustomer = form.save()
            newCustomer.company = company
            newCustomer.save()
            return redirect('user:customer_list')
    else:
        form = form_class()

    return render(request, 'customer.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Isn't [this](https://github.com/django-money/django-money#working-with-exchange-rates) is not what you're looking?

Comment: I cannot understand how to use it